# CSS: apply style only on <a> without inner <img>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to apply style to hovered links in a list, but only if there is not image inside `<a>` element.

The markup is like this:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://cso.cz/wpimages/cz2.gif"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
div#leftcolumn ul a:hover{ 
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  color: Black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid Black; 
}
```

I have tried this css, but to no avail:

```
div#leftcolumn ul a:hover < img{ 
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  color: Black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid Black; 
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxophed/)

Comment: Are you forced to this HTML? If not, you could wrap text in a `<span>` and apply rules there.

Comment: Have you tried `a:not(a img):hover{ ... }` - untested

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Pseudo selector :not() wont accept complex selector in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You cannot do this with css, you will need some js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible in pure CSS.

However, you could wrap text in a `<span>` and only apply rules there, i.e. something like:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><span>google</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://cso.cz/wpimages/cz2.gif"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#leftcolumn ul a:hover > span { 
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  color: Black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid Black; 
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxophed/1/)

Comment: This is Good, But if there is no Span Ho can make it Work ?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot style an element based on it's children in CSS, what you can do is assign a special class for `<a>` tags that hold the image and prevent styling it:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com" class="withImage"><img src="http://cso.cz/wpimages/cz2.gif"></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>

div#leftcolumn ul a:not(.withImage):hover{ 
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  color: Black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid Black; 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: if you are going to put a class on the anchor, why not just put it on the one with text and target that rather than on the one with the image and targetting not that?

Answer (score 0):

add **.non-img** to li which is without img
n do css with using **.non-img**

```css
div#leftcolumn ul li.non-img a:hover{ 
  background-color: #F8F8F8; 
  color: Black; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid Black; 
  border-top: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<div id="leftcolumn">
      <ul>
        <li class="non-img"><a href="http://google.com">google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://cso.cz/wpimages/cz2.gif"></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```